# Minimal Docker Image for PHP-CLI execution

Tags: php, bash, docker

I want to run a php script as a oneliner from the command line. Since on this linux machine no PHP is installed but Docker I thought about executing the PHP interpreter by running an little PHP Docker image which executing the script and deletes the container and image after finishing.

My internet connection is not fast and thus the image should be as small as possible.

The script `process.php` should read the File `data.json` in the current working directory and generate some text files in subdirectories. So no special PHP modules are required.

My questions:

- Which small/minimal ready-to-use-image on Dockerhub is recommended?
- How small is this image?
- How to write the one liner `docker run ...` to be executed on the Linux command line (`bash`)?

My research on Dockerhub resulted in tons of PHP images with full blown PHP and not optimized on Host volume modifications as a one liner.

Comment: So what have you tried :-) and researched

Comment: This will no doubt change in time.  But check docker hub.  https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ I'm running the zts-alpine, which is smallish (approx 60MB).

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I searched over two hours without a good solution. I edited the question.

Comment: @Progrock: I saw php:5.6.33-zts-alpine3.4 has a sife of 43.36 MB. Fine. But how to write the one liner?

Comment: BTW: what means "zts"?

Comment: What's wrong with Php latest?

Comment: OK, "php:7.2.2-zts-alpine3.7" is 63 MB. Not bad, but php:5.6.33-zts-alpine3.4 is better. I don't need latest features. How about the command line?

Comment: ZTS is Zend thread safety, see: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php , plenty of docker tutorials on the web.  I'm no authority,

Comment: Your question i running a bit broad, but without any other info, I would start with `7.1-cli-alpine` or `7.2-cli-alpine`, do some research on how to run it and come back with any specific problems you ran into.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution close to what I need.

The script `process.php`:

```
<?php
echo "hello";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__."/data.json"),true);
file_put_contents("message.txt","message is ".$data["message"]);
```

The data file `data.json`:

```
{
    "message": "hello world"
}
```

The one-liner:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp \ 
php:7.2.2-cli-alpine3.6 php process.php
```

And the result is `message.txt`:

```
message is hello world
```

Not the smallest image, but has a size of 62 MB and removes itself after finishing.